# Independent variables in conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

So I am reading this paper about reasoning(Hall, Ali, Chater, & Oaksford, 2016). Consider this conditionals.

```
If the fuse blows (p) then the lights go out (q)
If there is a power cut (r) then the lights go out (q)
```

Basically two independent causes that can make the lights go out. A few lines from (Hall, Ali, Chater, & Oaksford, 2016) really confuse.

```
So, the probability of the fuses blowing (p) is independent of power
cuts (r). 
However, they are not independent if the effect is known to have occurred, i.e., Pr(p|r,q) != Pr(p|q). 
Indeed, it is easily proven that Pr(p|r, q) < Pr(p|q)
```

From my basic understanding of conditional probability if p and r are independent their probabilities should be independent, regardless of the consequent.

Hall, S., Ali, N., Chater, N., & Oaksford, M. (2016). Discounting and augmentation in causal conditional reasoning: Causal models or shallow encoding? PLoS ONE, 11(12). https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0167741

Answer (score 2):

The authors are pointing out that two events that are unconditionally independent can be dependent when conditioned on a third event. For example, toss a fair coin twice. Let $H_1$ be the event that the first toss lands heads, and let $H_2$ be the event that the second toss lands heads. Then $H_1$ and $H_2$ are independent, i.e.,
$$
P(H_1\mid H_2)=\frac12=P(H_1).
$$ Now consider the event $Q$ that at least one head is observed on two tosses. You can check that
$$P(H_1\mid H_2, Q) = \frac12\ne \frac23 = P(H_1\mid Q),
$$
which is saying that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not independent given $Q$. (Note the event $Q$ is a consequent of both $H_1$ and $H_2$.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you get the 2/3?